# Chating functianlity with push notifications in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IPhone creating a chat application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375645/iphone-creating-a-chat-application)

hi..
  i want to integrate chating functionality with push notifications concepts for iphone.Can anybody Explain regarding this and what is process for this?

Comment: See also: [chat application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867143/chat-application)

Answer (score 0):

About explaining the Push-method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

The push-method describes a style of Internet-based communication where the request for a given transaction is initiated by the publisher or central server.

It is contrasted with pull technology, where the request for the transmission of information is initiated by the receiver or client.

In short: your server pushes a message to your app, and your app listens to that. Instead of updating each time yourself, your server basically decides when to update your app.